# Alternate drivers for an Epson Stylus C88

Tags: drivers, printer, terminal-services

My clients use an EMR that is very particular with printers. One of the clients uses an Epson Stylus C88 but the software ignores the driver, so it can't see the printer. When my client tries to print, they get squat.

Historically, you could assign any HP LaserJet the HP LaserJet 4 driver and it would print. That's probably because the LaserJet 4 was so basic; all the instructions worked across the board.

Is there a similar driver for the Epson Stylus C88? I've tried many drivers, but printing never works for me.

Comment: You're using a terminal server connection?  What's the OS and version on the client, and on the TS?  Is the printer local to the client, or attached via some other method (print server, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a TS then you need a printer that supplies TS-compatible drivers; and it doesn't appear that that consumer grade ink-jet for printing photos is intended (nor provide compatible drivers) for terminal server usage (it's pretty much guaranteed to be a 'host-based' printer/drive, which almost never work with TS, and almost never have a 'universal' type driver).

The reason the LaserJets could get away with the older LJ4 driver was/is because decent LaserJets speak common printer languages like PCL and PostScript, so the driver just sends the print job in one of those, and the printer processes the commands into a print-out.  Host-based printers do this processing at the 'host' (your computer) and send it to the printer as a processed print-out in some proprietary format.

In general, if MS doesn't provide a driver via Windows Update, and you've tried the latest from Epson, you may be (probably are) out of luck getting it to work across the terminal server.

If you are using Server 2008R2 on the TS, then you may be able to use it with Easy Print, if it's implemented.

We'll need more clarification on the actual setup to be able to offer better suggestions.

Comment: You, sir, win one Internetz. You're correct. It's a crappy, inkjet mess that was never intended for office use. But I'm sure you're well aware that cost trumps intentions every time. I appreciate your response. I just needed someone else to say it, I suppose. "Sorry, bud. You're SOL." To answer your statements, I have indeed checked for updated drivers and universal alternatives, to no avail. Thanks, again.